# Why JSOUP does not read as UTF-8?

Tags: java, html, utf-8, jsoup

I want to jsoup parse as utf -8 but I cant. I try everything I know and I searched on google.

What is my goal:

```
String tmp_html_content ="Öç";

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(tmp_html_content.getBytes());            
Document doc_tbl  =  Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", ""); 
doc_tbl.outputSettings().charset().forName("UTF-8");
doc_tbl.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
```

But `doc_tbl`  is not `UTF-8`.

please help about that

Comment: you can try ISO-8859-9 insteaf of UTF-8

Comment: did u get error or what output generated

Comment: it still diffferent charas like &Ccedil; it does not give error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        String tmp_html_content ="Öçasasa";

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(tmp_html_content.getBytes());            
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc_tbl;
        try {
            doc_tbl = Jsoup.parse(is, "ISO-8859-9", "");
              ((org.jsoup.nodes.Document) doc_tbl).outputSettings().charset().forName("UTF-8");
                ((org.jsoup.nodes.Document) doc_tbl).outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
                String htmlString = doc_tbl.toString();
                System.out.println(htmlString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 

     }
```

### out put

Hello World

 
 
  Öçasasa

Comment: on my jsoup (1.7.3) the output is this-> Hello World
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  ÃÃ§asasa
 </body>
</html>

Comment: @virgula24 u can use ISO-8859-1 charset