# Scrape a website with Jsoup which uses a URL with non-Latin characters

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to make a program in java that will get the schedule of my school classes, and notify me when I have free-hours. The problem is the the URL of the page which contains the schedule, contains Hebrew characters, and the Jsoup library can't access it.
The url is: [http://b7rabin.iscool.co.il/מערכתשעות/tabid/217/language/he-IL/Default.aspx](http://b7rabin.iscool.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA/tabid/217/language/he-IL/Default.aspx)  (it's not www)
And I don't know how to make my program to get access to that url.
It also contains javascript links to open different classes' schedules, and I would like to know how I can make my program to open those javascript links and get the info from them.

Comment: This [previous SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12466923/4718923) should solve your problem. Basically you need to URL-encode your url before passing it to Jsoup.

Comment: @lleaff URLs with only english characters works fine for me, my problem is just with the encoding of the hebrew characters in Jsoup. could you try yourself to scrap this url?

Comment: Did you try the solution I linked you? It's very likely to work.

Comment: @lleaff I just get an exception.. http://prntscr.com/e55aqq

Comment: Did you also try the advice in the comment underneath the linked solution ?

Comment: @DuKes0mE Yeah, it didn't work

Comment: How about this then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24219958/2245646 You may need to test different encodings

Comment: I've tried the following piece of code: `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://b7rabin.iscool.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA/tabid/217/language/he-IL/Default.aspx")
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .get();` and got the `HTML` of the site. Which Java and Jsoup versions are you using? You should add your code to your question.

Comment: @TDG it worked, that's all I needed. What does the userAgent do?

Comment: It tells the server which browser (also known as "client") you are using. Some sites have different pages for different clients - they look different if you browse them from PC or mobile. בהצלחה!

Comment: @TDG Now I have another problem, The page I want to access is running js codes in order to navigate through different tables. so:
1) I have the javascript commands that are needed, but how do I execute them on the page.
2)How do I get the HTML code from this page after launching those js codes?