# Polish characters in file java

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I using in my project `Jsoup`. I read docx file and convert it to html. I want write results in file, but I have problem. FileOutputStream not write polish characters. For example instead of

`Wiersz nad którym znajduje się aktualnie kursor myszy`
I have

```
Wiersz nad kt?rym znajduje si� aktualnie kursor myszy .
```

This is my method where I parse html:

```
public String parseHTML(String html) {
    int i = 0;
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    doc.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml).charset("ISO-8859-2");
    for (Element element : doc.select("img[src]")) {
        element.attr("src", "resources/images/img" + i + ".png");
        i++;
    }
    return doc.toString();
}
```

and here I write to file:

```
public void saveHelpFile(byte[] document) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(
            "path/to/file");
    String s = new String(document, "ISO-8859-2");
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "ISO-8859-2");
    try {
        writer.write(s);
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Here is my method where I read file:

```
public void uploadFile() throws XWPFConverterException, IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/file"));
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);

        XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create();
        XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

        String html = out.toString();
        html = html.replaceAll("<html>",
                "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' " + "\n" + " xmlns:h='http://java.sun.com/jsf/html' " + "\n"
                        + " xmlns:f='http://java.sun.com/jsf/core' " + "\n" + " xmlns:p='http://primefaces.org/ui ' "
                        + "\n" + " xmlns:ui='http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets' " + "\n"
                        + " xmlns:pe='http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions' " + "\n"
                        + " xmlns:components='http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components' >");

        html = parseHTML(html, extractPhoto(document));
        html = html.replaceAll("<body>", "<h:body>").replaceAll("</body>", "</h:body>");
        saveHelpFile(html.getBytes("ISO-8859-2"));
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `byte[] document` contains bytes in `ISO-8859-2` encoding? Are you sure it's not `UTF-8`?

Comment: maybe this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218239/why-jsoup-does-not-read-as-utf-8

Comment: Polish characters will also be displayed correctly when using the UTF-8 character set encoding

Comment: @Kayaman but when I print string before write is ok, so problem is when I write it

Comment: Then how are you reading the file? The file is in `ISO-8859-2`, so you need to make sure that it's being treated as such. It's also quite unnecessary to convert the `byte[]` to a `String`. You might just as well write the bytes directly with a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @Kayaman I print results before write and in string is allright but after write in result file I don't have polish characters.

Comment: How do you read the file. What do you do to see what's inside the file.

Comment: I edit my question @Kayaman

Comment: Yet you still don't answer my question. What are you doing when you see `Wiersz nad kt?rym znajduje si� aktualnie kursor myszy`? What's the last action that you, as a human being took before seeing that?

Comment: @Kayaman I print it before write for example: `System.out.println(s);
   writer.write(s);` Unless, maybe you talk about place when I pass document argument.

Comment: You just said that it looks okay if you print it out before writing: "when I print string before write is ok". I asked about after writing.

Comment: @Kayaman after write I refresh page and check my result file in browser.

Comment: And when doing that, are you indicating that the file is in `ISO-8859-2`?

Comment: @Kayaman If I copy content of string directly to file is ok so I don't think that is problem in file.

Comment: If you change `new PrintWriter(file, "ISO-8859-2");` to `new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");`, what happens?

Comment: @Kayaman yes , it's working! Thanks.

Comment: Of course it is, but I'm not sure you understand why it's working. You'll also note that your "I don't think that is problem in file" statement was completely false. Don't trust your instincts too much.

Comment: @Kayaman Now I know where was problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your String is fine, it contains correct info, but when you write to file you write it with charset "ISO-8859-2". File doesn't keep the charset info it is written with. Whatever app reads the file it is expected to know or guess the charset of the file. That's why it is always recommended to write your files in UTF-8 or UTF-16. So, in your code no change is needed as far as getting your String. Just when you write to file change the charset to UTF-8. The reason that it will work is that you "told" your String that your bytes represent info in charset "ISO-8859-2" and should be interpreted as such. So the String is built correctly. But internally java keeps all Srtings in Unicode charset (UCS-2). So now you can write your String to any other destination (file in your case) in any valid charset and Java will know how to write it. So in your case you can write it in "ISO-8859-2" or in "UTF-8" or any other charset that supports Polish (for instance "UTF-16") Since UTF-8 is generally accepted de-facto standard it is recommended to use it

Answer (score 1):

Use Charset.defaultCharset(). It worked for me.

Comment: yes it worked for me too